# CSS background color not reflecting

Tags: css, frontend, background-color, liveserver, live-sass-compiler

So I am following along with a youtube tutorial to set up my VSCode on front-end development for beginners. Heres the link to the video. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aydFCQiUW44&list=WL&index=10&ab_channel=CoderCoder

My issue is that as I follow along step by step when it's time to check my page to ensure that everything is showing live, everything is showing except the background color.  The uploader has her comments turned off so I can't ask what I am missing so I am searching here for help.  Here's the code. I am using the live sass compiler by Glenn Marks. the Live sasscompiler by Ritwick Dey prompts me to use that one instead, and I am also using the Live server by Ritwick Dey.

```
html {
    font-size: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

*, *::before, *::after {
    box-sizing: inherit;
}

body {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    line-height: 1.3;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    background-color: #202020;
    color: #ffffff;
}
```

was expecting to see the background in black (dark grey) with white text. but instead its just white background with black text.

Comment: @BernardBorg Linking the video would be disallowed by the rules, OP, please include your HTML with the question

Comment: Can't reproduce: https://jsfiddle.net/h03r5u7o/1/

Comment: sorry. i just linked it. sorry im still new at this. what did you mean that i cant reproduce?

Comment: [Read](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) this on how to reproduce your answer